# WMI Query not work with dates in removable devices

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service

I am trying to create a WMI Event query that notify me when a new file is created on the device whit this query  `"SELECT * From __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 Where TargetInstance ISA \"CIM_DATAFile\" And TargetInstance.Drive=\"" + driveUnit.Name.Replace("\\", "") + "\" And TargetInstance.CreationDate > \"" + ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDmtfDateTime(markfInstallation) + "\"");`, but i have two problems:

1. when I plug the device, this query notify me for all files created previously in the device (the same when I remove the device but with __InstanceDeletionEvent)
2. For try to solve this i trying to filter this query using the TargetInstance.CreationDate, but there is the second problem, when read CreationDate for a file on the removable device the format is like `20220207123159.630000+***`, I think that the problems is about "+***" but this only happend on removable device, and i dont know how to convert it ot something for use in a query (if make this for c: unit for example, the date get correctly de offset time, and works

I would like how to make the query for using CreatedDate in remable devices and compare it with other values

Comment: In PowerShell: `[datetime]::ParseExact('20220207123159.630000+***', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff\+\*\*\*', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`. In C# (I think) `DateTime.ParseExact("20220207123159.630000+***", "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff\+\*\*\*", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: the problem is that i am programming in c# using a WqlEventQuery, and here i must make the query like string and i cant parse nothing i think, the query is:
 "SELECT * From __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 Where TargetInstance ISA \"CIM_DATAFile\" And TargetInstance.Drive=\"" + driveUnit.Name.Replace("\\", "") + "\" And TargetInstance.CreationDate > \"" + ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDmtfDateTime(markfInstallation) + "\"");